# Lazy evaluations with std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, overloading

I'm trying to realize lazy evaluations of summation of std::vectors.

```
  template <class L, class OpTag, class R>
struct Expression
{
    Expression(const L &rcL, const R &rcR)
        : m_rcL(rcL), m_rcR(rcR)
    { }
    double  operator [] (unsigned index) const
    {
        return OpTag::apply(m_rcL[index], m_rcR[index]);
    }
    const L &m_rcL;
    const R &m_rcR;
};

struct OpAdd;

template <class L, class R>
Expression <L, OpAdd, R> operator + (
    const L &rcL, const R &rcR)
{
    return Expression <L, OpAdd, R>(rcL, rcR);
}

struct OpAdd
{
    static double apply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

template <class TExpr>
std::vector<double> & std::vector<double>::operator = (const TExpr &rcX)
{
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < this->size(); ++i)
        (*this)[i] = rcX[i];
    //
    return *this;
}
```

which returns the next error:

> Error C2244   'std::vector>::operator =':
>   unable to match function definition to an existing
>   declaration

As I can see, the problem is in overloading of assign operator of std::vectors. How to fix the error?

Comment: Do you know that definition requires declaration if done outside the class? Also messing with standard library except some small cases is UB.

Comment: Everything is wrong. You can't arbitrarily add member functions to standard library types.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), for sure.

Comment: If you want `Texpr` to be convertible to vector of doubles, use user defined implicit conversion operator.

Comment: I've edited the question

Comment: It seems like you need expression templates.

Comment: Just write normal function instead of `operator =`

Comment: Thanks for advice.  I'll write a wrapper for std::vector.